# How to retrieve and display all field data which is stored in one column only in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is all field input data stored in database in one column like this

```
a:3:{s:12:"ufbl_field_1";s:6:"John";s:12:"ufbl_field_2";s:9:"john@gmail.com";s:12:"ufbl_field_3";s:10:"some text";}
```

So How to retrieve this type of data and display it in CodeIgniter framework where column name is `ENTRY_DETAIL`.

Because Normally we have each separate column for each data input but here all data is inserted in one column,how to fetch and display that.

Comment: Its serialize format. You can get data using `unserialize` function of PHP

Answer (score 0):

First of all get your column data with query like so

```
$result=$this->db->select('ENTRY_DETAIL')->where('user_id',1)->get('tablename')->row();
```

then

```
$data['result']=unserialize($result->ENTRY_DETAIL);
 $this->load->view('pagename',$data);//pass the data to view
```

and then in view

```
foreach($result as $key=> $value)
   {
       echo $key.':'.$value;
   }
```

Hopefully, it works

Comment: Thanks Namdhari Plz check i posted my controller code its giving undefined variable error

Answer (score 0):

Check my code its showing undefined varible result

Controller:

```
public function data()
{
    $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');
    $data['result']=$this->articles->data();
    $this->load->view('public/data',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function data()
{
    $result=$this->db->select('data')->where('id',189)->get('articles')->row();
    $result=unserialize($result->data);
    return $result;
}
```

View :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    foreach($result as $key=> $value)
    {
       echo $key.':'.$value;
    }
    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Namdhari thanks for your help it works, but i am trying to display all rows by removing WHERE CLAUSE it giving error.